# why is my Java object being copied or finalize() being called twice?

Tags: java, android, debugging, android-ndk, finalize

Long Java/Android/JNI story short... I have two classes, an object/class which I created called Packet, and a JNI interface to lower-level C code that I wrote.  In one class, I parse incoming packets and store them in an ArrayList. When they are "parsed" a function Packet.dissect() is called, which uses JNI to call lower-level C-code.  This C-code malloc()'s some memory, and returns the memory pointer to the Java code which stores it in a private member of the Packet object:

```
ArrayList<Packet> _scan_results;

    ...

        // Loop and read headers and packets
        while(true) {
            Packet rpkt = new Packet(WTAP_ENCAP_IEEE_802_11_WLAN_RADIOTAP);

            switch(_state) {

            case IDLE:
                break;

            case SCANNING:
                // rpkt.dissect() calls a JNI C-code function which allocates
                // memory (malloc) and returns the pointer, which is stored in
                // a private member of the Packet (rpkt._dissect_ptr).
                rpkt.dissect();
                if(rpkt.getField("wlan_mgt.fixed.beacon")!=null)
                    _scan_results.add(rpkt);

                break;
            }
        }
```

Now, I want to ensure that this memory is freed so that I do not have a leak.  So, when the garbage collector determines that the Packet object is no longer in use, I rely on finalize() to call a JNI C-code function, passing the pointer, which frees the memory:

```
protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
    try {

        if(_dissection_ptr!=-1)
            dissectCleanup(_dissection_ptr);

    } finally {
        super.finalize();
    }
}
```

Great, this works just fine *UNTIL* I attempt to share the ArrayList with the second class.  To do so, I use Broadcast in Android by sending a broadcast with the ArrayList list from the first class, to a BroadcastReceiver in the second class.  Here is where it is broadcast from the first class:

```
    // Now, send out a broadcast with the results
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setAction(WIFI_SCAN_RESULT);
    i.putExtra("packets", _scan_results);
    coexisyst.sendBroadcast(i);
```

What I *thought* was true about doing this, would be that each Packet in the list is passed to the second class by reference to the object.  If this were true, then no matter what the two classes do with the List and the objects in them, I am guaranteed that the garbage collector will only call finalize() *ONCE* for each Packet (when both classes are deemed finished with each packet).  This is super important, or free() will be called twice on the same pointer (causing a SEGFAULT).

This seems to be happening to me.  Once the second class receives the ArrayList from the broadcast, it parses through it, and holds several Packet's from the list.  When doing so, there is another object/class which has a member of type Packet, if I "like" the packet, I save it by doing:

```
other_object.pkt = pktFromList;
```

Eventually this method which received the Broadcast returns, and some of the Packets were "kept."  Finally, when I click a button (several seconds later), the ArrayList in the original class is cleared:

```
_scan_results.clear();
```

I have assumed that even when clear() is called here, if the first class has "kept" some of the packets, the garbage collector will not call finalize() on them.  The only way for this to be false would be if: (1) when the broadcast is sent, the ArrayList is copied and not passed by reference, or (2) when the packets are "kept" in the second class, the Packet object is copied rather than being kept by reference.

Well, one of these is false because free() is occasionally called on the same piece of memory twice.  I see that it is allocated ("new dissection: MEMORY_ADDRESS1 - IGNORE_THIS"), and then two finalize() are called trying to deallocate the same memory address:

```
INFO/Driver(6036): new dissection: 14825864 - 14825912
...
INFO/Driver(6036): received pointer to deallocate: 14825864
...
INFO/Driver(6036): received pointer to deallocate: 14825864
INFO/DEBUG(5946): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr 0000001c
```

So, one of the two assumptions I am making about the objects being passed around is false.  Does anyone know which it might be, and how I can pass the objects more carefully by reference so that I can clean the memory up properly?

If you made it this far through my question and understand it, thank you ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intent extras are passed by value, not by reference.  This means a copy of whatever is being passed is created by the receiver when it receives the intent.

Presumably you have marked your Packet class as a Parcelable-- in order to get it to work as an intent extra.  Parcelables are marshaled and unmarshaled -- you should change your marshaling code for Packet to drop the memory pointer so it won't be passed on to the copy so it can't be released twice.

(Expanding, based on comments below and requirement that it act "as if" it had been passed by reference)

Create a global `HashMap<int,ArrayList<Packet>> passed_packets;`

When creating the intent, add the object now being passed as an extra to the HashMap:

```
synchronized(passed_packets) {
    passed_packets.put(_scan_results.hashCode(), _scan_results);
}
```

Add the hash key to the intent in lieu of the actual object

```
i.addExtra("packets_key", _scan_results.hashCode())
```

When receiving the intent, get the hash key, get the value from the HashMap, and remove it from the HashMap

```
synchronized(passed_packets) {
    int key = i.getInt("packets_key");
    scan_results = passed_packets.get(key);
    passed_packets.remove(key);
}
```

Comment: This gets a little tricky then.  I made my Packet class Serializable for it work with as an intent extra.

It is tricky because that pointer is actually used for something by both classes.  If I don't pass the pointer to the second class, then it cannot use my entire purpose for it.  If the first class frees the pointer before the second class gets to use it, then it again defeats my purpose :)

It is essential that the object is passed by reference somehow, or my whole scheme of how things work and will be deallocated will not work.

Comment: @gnychis -- You can't pass the thing as an intent extra; put it in your application object or some global HashMap and just pass the key with your intent.  You can use the default object hashcode as the key.  Then the receiver can remove it so you don't have a dangling reference and it will clean up as you expect.

Comment: Hmmm... if I do it this way, as having some global HashMap or something like that, it may also be tough.  Essentially, the two classes are in two different threads.  What I was hoping with the whole Broadcast and Intent stuff, is that both threads could run and use the Packets without me having to worry about when both are done.  But now it seems like I would need to decide when to remove the object from the Hashmap so that the memory is actually eventually freed. At which point, finalize() and the GC are of no help to me. Or am I missing something about your suggested approach?

Comment: I had asked this question to see if my objects would be copied by reference or object across my threads, such that this would be simpler.  Here is a link to my question which made me think this would all work (with background on the threading part): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6779019/when-will-finalize-be-called-on-my-class-instance-in-this-scenario

Comment: @gnychis -- If you use my approach and the receiver removes the reference in the global hashtable as soon it receives the intent, it should be the same as if it were passed by reference.  If it is sent from different thread, you will have to wrap access to passed_packets with synchronize(passed_packets) {

Comment: ahhhh, I understand now!  I am essentially trying to bypass the Broadcast Intent where it is copied by object.  This makes sense to me now.  When you say "if it is sent from a different thread, you will have to wrap access to passed_packets..." - can you just briefly elaborate on this?  I don't understand the importance/significance.  Thanks for your help, I sincerely appreciate it.

Comment: I've updated my example code to indicate how you should protect access to global hash so different threads see it consistently

Comment: thanks so much, I appreciate your time and understanding!  I will give this a shot :)

Comment: One last thing.  Part of the reason for using Broadcast was that an unknown number of threads could receive the data and do something with it.  It's not critical to me right now because I only have two threads.  But do you have any ideas on how to extend this in that way?  The reason your method works for only two threads, is that the receiver of the broadcast removes the key.  Once it is removed, another thread may not be able to retrieve the packets, etc.

Comment: At this point I start to suspect that you are using Intents for something for which they are in fact ill-suited :)  Instead of explicitly removing the object from a HashMap, you want to be using a WeakHashMap, but that introduces an additional layer of complexity and you will have a problem if the only reference to th object is within the Intent distribution system.

Comment: hehe, understandable.  Do you know of some other primitive I should/could be using instead that is more suited for this?  I basically construct a list of Packets, then I want to broadcast them out to whatever threads are listening, then GC to collect (ensuring finalize() is called once per Packet object).  I only have two threads right now, but I'm thinking near future and for future design of other related things

Comment: @gnychis let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1960/discussion-between-antlersoft-and-gnychis)